# How to created two file from one file, using as criterion the number of column

Tags: linux, edi, bigdata

I need to create two files from one file. The condition is:
If a number of column in rows of input is equal to 11, the rows will copy to output1.
If a number of column in a rows of input is equal to 10, the rows will copy to output2.

example *input* with less column:

```
Id_animal Id_SNP Farm Allele
ID01 rs01 A 1
ID02 rs01 1
ID03 rs01 B 2
ID04 rs01 0
```

In this case, the row 1 and row 3 will go to output1 and row 2 and 3 will go to output2.

*output1*

```
ID01 rs01 A 1
ID03 rs01 B 2
```

*output2*

```
ID02 rs01 1
ID04 rs01 0
```

But in my case, the number of a row is 45927948 and the number max of a column is 11 and min 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk you can do it like this `awk -f script.awk input` and script.awk is:

```
NR == 1 { next }
NF == 4 { print > "output1" }
NF == 3 { print > "output2" }
```

- Modify the 4 and 3 in the condition on `NF` (the number of fields in the line).
- The first line skips the header.